# Handle nested pagination in ElasticSearch 6.8

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I would like to paginate over a nested array in Elasticsearch 6.8

The initial pagination was handled at high-level (item)

```
|-item.1
|   |-id                |
|   |-dataType          |
|   |-approvals         |
|       |-approval.1A   |
|       |-approval.1C   |
|-item.2                |
|   |-id                |
|   |-dataType          |
|   |-approvals         |
|       |-approval.2A   |
|       |-approval.2B   |
|       |-approval.2C __|__  page 1, size=2 , offset=0
|-item.3                |
|   |-id                |
|   |-dataType          |
|   |-approvals         |
|       |-approval.3A   |
|       |-approval.3B   |
|       |-approval.3C   |
|       |-approval.3D   |
|       |-approval.3E   |
|-item.4                |
|   |-id                |
|   |-dataType          | 
|   |-approvals         |
|       |-approval.4A   |
|       |-approval.4B   |
|       |-approval.4C __|__ page 2, size=2, offset=2
|-item.5                | 
|   |-id                |
|   |-dataType          | 
|   |-approvals         |
|       |-approval.5A   |
|       |-approval.5C   |
|       |-approval.5E __|_
|-item.6                | 
...
```

Whether now this has to be amended to the below format and adjusted to paginate through the nested values (approvals)

```
|-item.1
|   |-id
|   |-dataType
|   |-approvals       __ __
|       |-approval.1A   |
|       |-approval.1B   |
|-item.2                |
|   |-id                |
|   |-dataType          | page 1, size=5, offset=0
|   |-approvals         |
|       |-approval.2A   |
|       |-approval.2B   |
|       |-approval.2C __|__
|-item.3                |
|   |-id                |
|   |-dataType          |
|   |-approvals         | page 2, size=5, offset=5
|       |-approval.3A   |
|       |-approval.3B   |
|       |-approval.3C   |
|       |-approval.3D   |
|       |-approval.3E __|__
|       |-approval.3F   |
|-item.4                |
|   |-id                |
|   |-dataType          | page 3, size=5, offset=10
|   |-approvals         |
|       |-approval.4A   |
|       |-approval.4B   |
|       |-approval.4C   |
|       |-approval.4D __|__
|-item.5
...
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Elasticsearch v6.8.8?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Have tried to use `inner_hits` in the query and add pagination to it but the problem there is that it will paginate the exact size on the nested array of each parent